# Is it possible to create a world with more than 3 planets in Space Engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

I'm wondering is it possible to create a world with more than 3 planets (not counting their moons) in Space Engineers? Or if I create `Custom World -> Easy Start 1` or `Easy Start 2` and when I travel far enough will I be able to find planets? Or if I get `Easy Start Earth` scenario will I find more than 3 planets in the world somewhere far enough? Is it possible at the moment? Because I've been unlucky so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game does not auto-generate planets currently, the only ones that will exist will be the ones that where put in when you load the map.

You can spawn new planets in while using creative mode or Space Master with creative tools enabled with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The [Space Engineers website](http://www.spaceengineersgame.com/space-engineers-now-with-planets.html) shows that only 3 types of planets are currently available. An Earth-like planet, a Mars-like planet, and an alien world. One can only assume that more will be introduced as time progresses.
(Taken from the above website):

FEATURES
(list truncated)

**Discover - three types of planets (inspired by Earth, Mars and an alien world)** with different biomes, atmospheres, resources and climate conditions, and three types of moons (inspired by the earth’s moon, Europa and Titan)

So short answer, no, not at this time. I can't see any reason why they would allow multiple copies of the same planet. Having two Earths would seem pointless if they were exactly the same.

Comment: There are tree types of planets, but they in fact have build more then 3 planets (all of them within those types). They confirmed this in their anniversary life-stream.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the update. I didn't realize that you could have multiple Earths, etc.